# Python : Iterate folders trough directory then rename folders with condition

Tags: python, loops, directory, rename

I'm looking for a way to iterate through folders (not files in it) in a repertory and renames them with a condition :
the condition will be the name of the folder itself : if it contains a certain str (who will be in a list) then nothing change. if not its name has to change with defined str

i get an error [WinError 183] who tells me that a renamed folder already exist..
can someone please help me ?
be nice with me i'm a beginner :)

here's my script :

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

list_of_str = ['apple', 'pumpkin', 'strawberry']
start_path = Path('C:\\Users\\jva\\Downloads\\here')

for dirname in os.listdir(start_path):
    f = os.path.join(start_path, dirname)

    if f == enumerate(list_of_str):
        pass
    else:
       os.rename(f,"SET_STR")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this instead of your `if...else` block:

```py
    matchedStr = [s for s in list_of_str if s in dirname]
    if matchedStr:
        os.rename(f,"SET_STR")
    else: pass # REDUNDANT
```

`matchedStr` will have any string from `list_of_str` that contains `dirname`, and an  empty list will evaluate to `False` the folder will not be renamed if there are no matches.

The `else` is completely unnecessary here (even `if x==y:....else: pass` is the same as just `if x!=y:..`), but some people prefer a certain format so I left it in incase of that.

Also, I have a feeling that you don't quite understand how python's `enumerate` works. Please take a look at [this tutorial](https://www.guru99.com/python-enumerate-function.html) at some point for further understanding.

Comment: thank you for your answer,
my bad for the enumerate , i just put it here for my own meaning but obviously this is not the appropriate thing :)
for dirname , i tried to set the variable as a windows path (with pathlib) but it return that a windows path is not iterable, any idea to avoid this problem ?

Comment: I think your current `os.listdir(start_path)` is just fine, but you could probably use something like `start_path.iterdir()` instead, if you want to use pathlib

Comment: Also, whether you end up using pathlib or os, you should add `f.is_dir()` or `os.path.isdir(f)` to the `if` conditions if you want to rename only folders and not files as well